# What function signatures are supported by Swagger/Connexion as endpoint handlers & use of "secret" keyword while linking endpoints to security scheme

Tags: python, flask, jwt, swagger, connexion

I am studying a Python Flask project which uses Connexion, Swagger, JWT, etc.
Below is the extract of the swagger.yaml and api.py file, in which I have changed names, so as not to post the original code:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: ALS
  version: "1.0"

paths:
  /als/endpoint1:
    post:
      summary: endpoint 1 summary here
      operationId: api.cls.func1
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
             
      responses:
        "200":
          description: secret response
          content:
            "application/json":
              schema:
                type: object

      security:
        - als-jwt: ["secret"]
    

components:
  securitySchemes:
    als-jwt:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
      x-bearerInfoFunc: auth.decode_token
```

My understanding is that when the endpoint `/als/endpoint1` is hit, Connexion will call the `decode_token` function in `auth.py`, and the `sub` property of the return value (probably a JWT Claim) will be passed in the `user` argument to the handler function `cls.func1` in `api.py`. The code extract of `api.py` is given a little below.

But I am not able to understand a few things:

1. What is the meaning and use of the keyword `secret` in the below snippet? Where can I get details of the other options / keywords that I can pass while linking the security scheme to the endpoint? I have seen other code examples on the internet, which only link the security scheme without passing any keyword like `secret`

```
    security:
        - als-jwt: ["secret"]
```

2. Following are some of the endpoint handler methods defined in `api.py` in the `class CLS`. All these methods `func1`, `func2`, `refresh_session` and `add_obj` are mapped to different endpoints in `swagger.yaml` file (which I have not shown above) and all these are linked to the security scheme `als-jwt`

```
class CLS():
    def func1(self, user, body):
        pass:
        
    def func2(self, body, user):
        pass:
        
    def refresh_session(user):
        pass:
        
    def add_obj(body):
        pass:
        
cls = CLS()
```

2a) How is the framework (`Connexion / Swagger`) able to call the functions, all with different signatures? Some functions are taking only a `user` parameter, some are taking only a `body` parameter, some are taking both `body` and `user` parameter but not in any particular order.

2b) What variations of the function signatures does the framework support for the endpoints? Where can I get specific documentation on this?

Comment: Should I break 1 and 2a, 2b into 2 separate questions? No response from the community